# Gridview Autosort Without allowing users to sort

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hello everyone here is the problem, and I hope you can help me

I use a Gridview in my asp.net page to show the data from my sql database.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="College" HeaderText="College" SortExpression="College"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The gridview itself is working fine but i want to auto sort by College but I DONT want the users to be able to sort anything on click. Hope you can help thanks.

Comment: Add sorting in sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Data-Source `SqlDataSource1` add `order by College`.

And change the bound filed

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name">
......
```

Set property of gridview `AllowSorting = false`